# Grafana , Prometheus - Calculating the average latency for external calls

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Looking for PromQL to calculate the average latency for both /catalog/* and /price/* calls

**prometheus metrics exposed**

```
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/catalog/product001"} 13.2
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/catalog/product002"} 10.5
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/catalog/product003"} 15.2
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/price/product001"} 5.2
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/price/product002"} 8.0
external_call_metric{method="GET",status="200",uri="/price/product003"} 2.5
```

I tried the below PromQL query, but its not aggregating the response time

```
sum(rate(external_call_metric{}[$__range])) by (method, uri)
```

Comment: What kind of metric are we talking about? Counter or Gauge? I guess Gauge?

Comment: The `rate` function can only be applied on counters - which would be the number of time the URL has been called. Is `external_call_metric` the last latency or the sum of all latencies ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez external_call_metric is having the last latency